# Laravel blade: Getting Undefined variable first time I load page, on refresh it works fine

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

**This is my route:** it works fine, I can see dumps if I do it inside the get Method and middleware is working fine as well

```
Route::get('account', 'AccountController@get')->middleware('auth');
```

**This is my controller:** I dump accountData and has value, also dump user and is the right user, so accountData is correct, but at first time loading the page comes variable undefined but if I refresh it loads fine

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{
   public function get()
   {
       $user = auth()->user();
       $account = $this->getAccountQuery($user->id);
       $accountData = $this->formatAccount($account, $user->id);
       return  view('account')->with($accountData);
   }
```

**This is the format method:**

```
  private function formatAccount($account, $userId): array
   {
        return [
            'accountId' => $account->id,
            'name' => (ucwords($account->first_name) . ' ' . ucwords($account->last_name)) ?? 'NA',
            'email' => $account->email ?? 'NA',
            'idType' => $account->id_type ?? 'NA',
            'idNumber' => $account->id_number ?? 'NA',
            'primaryTelephone' => $account->primary_telephone ?? 'NA',
            'secondaryTelephone' => !empty($account->secondary_telephone) ? $account->secondary_telephone : 'NA',
            'primaryAddress' => $account->primary_address ?? 'NA',
            'secondaryAddress' => !empty($account->secondary_address) ? $account->secondary_address : 'NA',
            'city' => ucwords($account->city) ?? 'NA',
            'country' => ucwords($account->country) ?? 'NA',
            'delivery' => $account->delivery,
            'pickup' => $account->pick_up,
            'authUsers' => $this->getAuthUsers($userId)
        ];
  }
```

**This is how I call it in my blade:**
If I refresh the page it works fine, only is happening the first time I load it

```
<p>
    <label id='label1'>Name
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder={{ $name }} required>
    </label>
</p>
```

Comment: please post the full error message you got.

Comment: try extracting the data in blade i.e. `extract $accountData;`

Comment: This is the error: [2020-02-25 19:36:16] production.ERROR: Undefined variable: name. Then path to line inside blade

Comment: Maybe you have to check this function: $this->getAccountQuery, it might be the one causing the problems..show us the code of it also to check if there's something wrong or not.

Comment: I can dump $account and see correct data, and on refresh pages loads fine, is just first time....